# Как работает выражение FORMSOF(INFLECTION, "книга") с русскими словами?

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос

- Насколько хорошо работает выражение `FORMSOF(INFLECTION, 'Книга')` с русскими словами?

Есть таблица  `Items(id,name, description)`

Ищу по ключевым словам как:

- Белая футболка
- синий шарф.

Могу ли найти товара с помощью такой запрос:

```
(FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, белая) AND FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, футболка)) 
OR (FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, синий) AND FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, шарф))
```

не судите строго я вообще новичок

Comment: Наверное без указания `LANGUAGE` при создании индекса и потом в самом запросе будет работать не очень хорошо

Comment: @DenisRubashkin, можете советовать полезные ссылки где можно изучить по этому вопросу? плз

Comment: [Здесь](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-full-text-search-language-features-part-2/) что-то про язык есть

Comment: @DenisRubashkin, спасибо))